# Forwarding stream messages to all clients connected in GRPC golang?

Tags: api, go, grpc

I have a GRPC Server with .proto file like this..

```
syntax = "proto3";

package chatserver;

message FromClient {

    string name = 1;
    string body = 2;
}

message FromServer {

    string name = 1;
    string body = 2; 
}

service Services {

    rpc ChatService(stream FromClient) returns (stream FromServer){};
}
```

and the server.go code looks like this..

```
package chatserver

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type messageUnit struct {
    ClientName        string
    MessageBody       string
    MessageUniqueCode int
    ClientUniqueCode  int
}

type messageHandle struct {
    MQue []messageUnit
    mu   sync.Mutex
}

var messageHandleObject = messageHandle{}

type ChatServer struct {
}

//define ChatService
func (is *ChatServer) ChatService(csi Services_ChatServiceServer) error {

    clientUniqueCode := rand.Intn(1e6)
    errch := make(chan error)
    println(csi.Context())

    // receive messages - init a go routine
    go receiveFromStream(csi, clientUniqueCode, errch)

    // send messages - init a go routine
    go sendToStream(csi, clientUniqueCode, errch)

    return <-errch

}

//receive messages
func receiveFromStream(csi_ Services_ChatServiceServer, clientUniqueCode_ int, errch_ chan error) {

    //implement a loop
    for {
        mssg, err := csi_.Recv()
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Error in receiving message from client :: %v", err)
            errch_ <- err
        } else {

            messageHandleObject.mu.Lock()

            messageHandleObject.MQue = append(messageHandleObject.MQue, messageUnit{
                ClientName:        mssg.Name,
                MessageBody:       mssg.Body,
                MessageUniqueCode: rand.Intn(1e8),
                ClientUniqueCode:  clientUniqueCode_,
            })

            log.Printf("%v", messageHandleObject.MQue[len(messageHandleObject.MQue)-1])

            messageHandleObject.mu.Unlock()

        }
    }
}

//send message
func sendToStream(csi_ Services_ChatServiceServer, clientUniqueCode_ int, errch_ chan error) {

    //implement a loop
    for {

        //loop through messages in MQue
        for {

            time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)

            messageHandleObject.mu.Lock()

            if len(messageHandleObject.MQue) == 0 {
                messageHandleObject.mu.Unlock()
                break
            }

            senderUniqueCode := messageHandleObject.MQue[0].ClientUniqueCode
            senderName4Client := messageHandleObject.MQue[0].ClientName
            message4Client := messageHandleObject.MQue[0].MessageBody

            messageHandleObject.mu.Unlock()

            //send message to designated client (do not send to the same client)
            if senderUniqueCode != clientUniqueCode_ {

                err := csi_.Send(&FromServer{Name: senderName4Client, Body: message4Client})

                if err != nil {
                    errch_ <- err
                }

                messageHandleObject.mu.Lock()

                if len(messageHandleObject.MQue) > 1 {
                    messageHandleObject.MQue = messageHandleObject.MQue[1:] // delete the message at index 0 after sending to receiver
                    fmt.Println("message greater then 1")
                } else {
                    messageHandleObject.MQue = []messageUnit{}
                }

                messageHandleObject.mu.Unlock()

            }

        }

        time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
    }
}
```

Now when e.g. three clients are connected to the server. If one client sends the message it is not being forwarded to the other two clients. It is only being sent to one of the other two clients. Can i somehow broadcast the message to all the other clients? or can i specify which client will receieve the message based on some client id?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to keep a global data structure containing all the connected streams and loop through them.
You will also need to generate a unique identifier for each one of them in order to differentiate.
I don't see any other way.